# App Engine + Google Documents

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, google-docs

What is the best way to access Google Documents (documents, spreasheets etc from Google Apps or Gmail) using Java on Google App Engine. We are using GWT on the client side.

Thanks,
Carl

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Data Client for Java](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/) suppose to work on the Google App Engine.
It gives you access to must of Google Apps Services.

---

Google has [Google Client API](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) which probably has a better support for OAuth2, json and support for the API discovery, but still The old API should work.
Read about [Migrating To Google Api Java Client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/wiki/MigratingToGoogleApiJavaClient) this should resolve any confusion you might have.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've looked at that page too but it says that development has stopped. I've also looked at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/ but am not sure if there is support for documents. I'm a bit confused.